# Why is this approach wrong？(Introduction to Probability Models 11th Edition)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Firstly, suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent exponential random variables with respective means $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$, so we can calculate the probability $P\{X_1<X_2\} = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. And we also know that for $n$ independent exponential random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ with respective means $\frac{1}{\lambda_1},\cdots,\frac{1}{\lambda_n}$, then the random variable $Y$ corresponding to the event $\min(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\frac{1}{\sum_{j = 1}^n \lambda_j}$.

Now consider for the same $n$ independent exponential random variables, what is the probability $P\{X_i = \min_j X_j\}$? In the book, it calculates the probability as follows
$$P\{X_i = \min_j X_j\} = P\{X_i < \min_{j\neq i}X_j\} = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_{j = 1}^n \lambda_j}$$
and I wonder why it cannot be calculate like this
$$P\{X_i = \min_j X_j\} = P\{X_i < \min_{j\neq i}X_j\}  = P\{X_i<X_j, \text{for all}\  j\neq i\} = \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}$$
I think the reason why this can't  hold may be that the event $X_i<X_k$ is not independent with $X_i<X_j$, but I cannot figure it out since $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are independent with each other.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Given $Y=\min X_i$, $Y$ is not independent from $X_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to see why your calculation cannot be correct is to consider the special case $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$ for all $i \ne j$; that is to say, the $X_i$ are iid with the same rate parameter.  Then by an obvious symmetry argument, $\Pr[X_i = \min_j X_j] = 1/n$, since each $X_i$ is equally likely to be the smallest.  But your calculation would imply the probability equals $1/2^{n-1}$ since each term in your product is $1/2$.

Why does your argument fail?  The first step,
$$\Pr[X_i = \min_j X_j] = \Pr[X_i < \min_{j \ne i} X_j]$$ is valid because the event that $X_i$ is the minimum among $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is true if and only if $X_i$ is strictly less than all of the observations other than itself.  And the second step, $$\Pr[X_i < \min_{j \ne i} X_j] = \Pr[X_i < X_j \text{ for all } j \ne i]$$ is also valid.  But the third step, $$\Pr[X_i < X_j \text{ for all } j \ne i] = \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j}$$ is most certainly wrong:  we can see this more clearly if we write out the intermediate step:

$$\Pr[X_i < X_j \text{ for all } j \ne i] \overset{?}{=} \prod_{j \ne i} \Pr[X_i < X_j].$$

Why can't you write this?  To understand what is happening, let's look at a simple numeric example:  suppose $X_1$ is unknown, but we have observed $(X_2, X_3) = (6,10)$; moreover, let $i = 1$.  So then the statement $X_i < X_j$ for all $i \ne j$ becomes $(X_1 < X_2) \cap (X_1 < X_3)$.  But the event $X_1 < X_2$ is **not** independent of the event $X_1 < X_3$, so you cannot write $$\Pr[(X_1 < X_2) \cap (X_1 < X_3)] = \Pr[X_1 < X_2]\Pr[X_1 < X_3].$$  You can think about this in a sequential way:  if $X_1 < X_2 = 6$, then this is **completely** informative of whether $X_1 < X_3$, since $X_3 = 10$.

So, the flaw occurs in the last step because the event $X_i < X_j$ for some $j \ne i$ is not independent of the event $X_i < X_k$ for some $k$ that is neither $j$ nor $i$.  The LHS of the inequality is the same random variable for all $j \ne i$.  So while the individual $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are indeed independent, the **events** $X_i < X_1$, $X_i < X_2$, $X_i < X_3$, and so forth, are not independent.

Then why does the author's solution work?  Simple.  There is only one event in the probability statement:  $$X_i < \min_{j \ne i} X_j$$ is not being expanded into multiple and dependent inequalities.  There is only one comparison being made, namely, between $X_i$ and the *minimum* of all of the other observations.  So there is no attempt to write this probability as the product of other probabilities.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you assume that if $$Y=\min{X_j}$$, then $$Y=X_i$$ This is not true. For example, $\min{X_1,X_2}$ is neither $X_1$ nor $X_2$. It is a different random variable.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening answer! I used to assume that if $Y = \min X_j$ then $Y = X_i \text{for some }i$.